# Xmodmap: On Lenovo Thinkpad T420 not working?

Tags: lenovo, thinkpad, xmodmap

I use a Lenovo ThinkPad T450 laptop (Linux 5.13.0-28-generic x86_64) with a german keyboard layout. Unfortunately the greater and lesser key is not available on this setup.
I can not switch the keys with xmodmap. My try to temporary reset the y key with following command fails:

```
xmodmap -e "keycode 52="
```

or

```
xmodmap -e 'keysym 0x0='
```

Only in xev I can see the system shouldn't print something if I press the y key. E.g.

```
KeyPress event, serial 34, synthetic NO, window 0xc00001,
    root 0x230, subw 0x0, time 1160810, (151,-18), root:(369,196),
    state 0x0, keycode 52 (keysym 0x0, NoSymbol), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

But outside of xev I get the output "y" or "Y" if I press the y-key.

What could be the reason for that and how can I change my keymapping on that laptop? Is their maybe some alternative way to do? But I don't want to change the keyboard to us layout.

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem with the space key, it didn't work
so first of all i did this:

```
xmodmap -pke
```

to see each key code, then this:

```
xmodmap -e 'keycode 64 = space NoSymbol space'
```

hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for your help, but this doesn't help as well. I still cleared all my pke file. But outside of xev it seems my changes don't have any effect.

Answer (score 0):

I found some solution. I just forget to start Ubuntu with xorg. I was abe to activate this on login.screen after I click on the settings button.[image]